# Como hago para cambiar un Entry de Tkinter StringVar a String

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy tratando de buscar una palabra especifica ingresada por el usuario en un dataframe y que el programa solo me imprima dicha palabra y su significado, sin embargo al ingresa la palabra y buscarla el programa me imprime todo el data frame y no la palabra especifica que estoy buscando.

```
 import pandas as pd
 from tkinter import *
 from tkinter import ttk
 import tkinter as tk

 excel_file = 'list1.xlsx'

 df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, usecols=['Phrasal Verb', 'Meaning'])

 raiz= tk.Tk()
 entrada=tk.StringVar()
 a=df[df['Phrasal Verb'].str.contains(entrada.get())]
 raiz.geometry("800x300")
 raiz.configure(background="White")
 raiz.title("Phrasal verbs App")
 frm = ttk.Frame(raiz, padding=10)
 frm.grid()
 entry = tk.Entry(frm, justify="center", textvariable=entrada).grid(column=3, row=0)
 tk.Button(raiz, text="Buscar Phrasal Verb", font=("Comic Sans", 10), bg="#00a8e8", fg = "white", command=lambda: print((a))).grid(column=3, row=0)
 raiz.mainloop()
```

Si lo uso asi si me funciona mas si lo intento con la entrada de texto me imprime el Dataframe completo.

```
 a=df[df['Phrasal Verb'].str.contains("On")]
```

¿Que debo hacer para que tome la entrada y la busque en el data frame?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: No le estás dando tiempo al usuario a escribir nada. Inicias la interfaz y al toque buscas el contenido del entry (que está en blanco y toda subcadena contiene una cadena vacía). Tenés que encontrar la forma de que el usuario le indique a tu programa "ya escribí la palabra, ahora buscala". Puede ser un botón o la tecla enter.

Comment: Gracias cree un nuevo boton y ahora funciona perfecto.

Comment: De nada Ismael c: